# is there a way to pass undefined.undefined as a function parameter

Tags: javascript

I want to check if object has a field with value then return default value if it has not..

```js
function testFun(value, defaultvalue) {
  if (!value) {
    console.log(defaultvalue)
  } else {
    console.log(value)
  }
}

let testVar
testFun(testVar, 'this is default vaue')
```

But this function should not care about passing value...
What if I want to pass:

```js
testVar.field1.value
```

Of course it will fail:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'field1' of undefined
```

So I need to pass any object and test its value without any ternary `?:` operators.

Comment: The function has nothing to do with checking for the undefined, it happens before you even call it. Unsure what the actual goal is....

Comment: Method parameters are evaluated before they are passed. If evaluating the parameter value itself already fails (for example because it involves reading a property from an undefined value), then there's nothing in the method definition you can do to avoid that.

Comment: If you are using a JS engine that supports [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) `testFun(testVar?.foo.value, 'this is default vaue')` If you do not have that option, you need to rethink this code.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way that you can do that is by using [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```js
function testFun(value, defaultvalue) {
  if (!value) {
    console.log(defaultvalue)
  } else {
    console.log(value)
  }
}

let testVar
testFun(testVar, testVar?.field1?.value || 'Other default value')
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you can do with the function to correct the error since it happens before the function is called.

If you are using a JS engine that supports [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) `testFun(testVar?.foo.value, 'this is default vaue')` If you do not have that option, you need to rethink this code.

```js
function testFun(value, defaultvalue) {
  if (!value) {
    console.log(defaultvalue)
  } else {
    console.log(value)
  }
}

let testVar
testFun(testVar?.foo.value, 'this is default value')
```

If you does not, you will have to do a truthy check of some sort

```js
function testFun(value, defaultvalue) {
  if (!value) {
    console.log(defaultvalue)
  } else {
    console.log(value)
  }
}

let testVar
testFun(testVar && testVar.foo && testVar.foo.value, 'this is default value')
```

or you have to alter the code to pass in the field you want to read and have it do the check in there

```js
function testFun(obj, key, defaultvalue) {
  const value = obj && obj.key && obj.key.value;
  if (!value) {
    console.log(defaultvalue)
  } else {
    console.log(value)
  }
}

let testVar
testFun(testVar, 'foo', 'this is default value')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [optional chaning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

```js
const testVar = {
  field1: null
};

const value = testVar.field1?.value;

console.log('Value:', value);
```

If you do not use optional chaning, you could [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the object, but keep-in-mind that the nested value's parent must default to an empty object.

```js
const testVar = {
  field1: {} // Needs to default to an object to extract value field
};

const { field1: { value } } = testVar;
 
console.log('Value:', value);
```

You could also [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) default values to the property as well. But you must spread the values at each level of the object.

```js
const defaultProps = {
  field1: {
    value: null
  }
}

const testVar = {
  field1: {
    value: 'foo'
  }
};

const { field1 } = testVar;
const combined = { ...defaultProps, field1: field1 };

const { field1: { value } } = combined;
 
console.log('Value:', value);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
function testFun(f, defaultvalue) {
  try {
    if (fn() === undefined) {
      return defaultvalue
    } else {
      return f()
    }
  } catch (e) {
    return defaultvalue
  }
}

let testVar
testFun(() => testVar.field1.value, 'this is default vaue')
```